# Is there source map support for typescript in node / nodemon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nodemon

I have a node project written in typescript@2.

My tsconfig has `sourceMap` set to `true` and the `*.map.js` files are generated. When I execute my transpiled `*.js` JavaScript files via `node` or `nodemon`, I only see the error messages relative to the `js` file and not to the mapped typescript files; I assume it's completely ignored.

Is `sourceMap` support only intended for browser-support? Or can I use it together with node or nodemon? If the latter, how would I enable it?

I want to see runtime errors detected from an executed javascript file relative to the original typescript file.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answers here are correct for Node versions before [v12.12.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v12.12.0/), which added the (experimental) [`--enable-source-maps`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/cli.html#cli_enable_source_maps) flag. With that enabled, source maps are applied to stack traces without an additional dependency. As demonstrated in [this article](https://nodejs.medium.com/source-maps-in-node-js-482872b56116), it has the slightly different and possibly beneficial behavior of including both the generated .js file location and the source file location. For example:

```
Error: not found
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bencoe/oss/source-map-testing/test.js:29:7)
        -> /Users/bencoe/oss/source-map-testing/test.ts:13:7
```

Comment: `NODE_OPTIONS=--enable-source-maps npm test` is the command I was looking for

Comment: I found that this didn't work unless I put `--enable-source-maps` BEFORE the path to the script file. Perhaps this is normal for Node command line switches; I'm not sure.

Comment: Note: There are complaints of `--enable-source-maps` slowing down requests (See https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/41541).  Maybe a little bit of polishing is required before we can use this in production.

Answer (score 43):

> for Node versions since v12.12, there is an [easier and better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64721153/8910547).

I recently got this working in my express app. Steps as follows:

Install the required library:

`npm install --save-dev source-map-support`

In your entry point (eg `app.ts`):

`require('source-map-support').install();`

In your `app.ts`, you may also require better logging for errors within promises:

`process.on('unhandledRejection', console.log);`

In your `tsconfig`, under `compilerOptions`:

`"inlineSourceMap": true`

Comment: inlineSourceMap and sourceMap compiler options are mutually exclusive

Comment: If you add the cli usage to your answer (as I pointed out in my own), I will accept yours and delete my own. ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/58455205/457268 )

Comment: @k0pernikus thanks. Apologies, not 100% sure I understand. Feel free to edit to my answer to show what you mean.

Comment: Any way to do this natively without bloating a package with `source-map-support`?

Comment: From node v12, you can use the flag `--enable-source-maps`

Answer (score 21):

Install source map support:

```
npm install source-map-support
```

(I run in in production as well, as it immensely helps finding bugs from the logs of when an error an occurs. I did not experience a large performance impact, yet your experience may be different.)

Add to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

When running your JavaScript file, add the require parameter:

```
nodemon -r source-map-support/register dist/pathToJson.js

node -r source-map-support/register dist/pathToJson.js
```

Alternatively, you add in your entry call:

```
require('source-map-support').install()
```

yet I find this tedious is projects with multiple entry points.

---

Sidenote: [mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha) also supports the [`--require`](https://mochajs.org/#-require-module-r-module) / `-r` option, so to have the sourcemap support in mocha you can also call your tests with it, e.g. similar to:

```
NODE_ENV=test npx mocha --forbid-only --require source-map-support/register --exit --recursive ./path/to/your/tests/
```

Answer (score 18):

I found this npm module which seems to do the trick:

https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support

run `npm install source-map-support --save` at the root of your node project and add `import 'source-map-support/register'` to your main.ts or index.ts file.

That's it.

Answer (score 8):

**For Node versions from v12.12.0**  use the --enable-source-maps flag when you run node.

Example: node --enable-source-maps main.js

**Do not install "source-map-support" for Node versions from v12.12.0**

Answer (score 6):

Source map support works perfectly fine with node

All you need to do is add

```
"source-map-support": "0.4.11",
```

to `dependencies` or `dev-dependencies` in `package.json` by running

```
npm install --save source-map-support
```

And in your entry point ts file, simply add at the top

```
require('source-map-support').install()
```

(note: this is calling nodeJS `require` - there is no need for source-map-support definition files)

Comment: Any downsides to using this in production? (server side)

Comment: @Sev Not as far as we know (we do use it in production)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using node (16.20.2) nyc(15.1.0) and mocha(8.1.3) this worked for me.

The error stack pointed me to the line 4:

[image]

### Solution

```js
npm install --save-dev source-map-support
```

**.nycrc.json**

```
{
  "include": "src/main",  
  "all": true
}
```

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {    
    "test": "NODE_OPTIONS=--enable-source-maps nyc --reporter=html --reporter=json-summary mocha 'src/test/node/**/*.test.js' --exit"
  }
```

The result error show the exact line 45 and extra information

[image]

Comment: Looks like that with such settings nyc doesn't report coverage