# How to display Typescript Runtime errors/exceptions in .ts instead of .js

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Im new to typescript. Im using a serverless solution from google (google cloud functions) that in the background is running Node.js with typescript.  When I get an "runtime error" in the logs I see an error in a .js file, this makes sense since .ts code is compiled to .js but it makes debugging a lot harder as I write typescript code and not javascript code. In general I would like to see the line that produced the error in .ts and not in .js. Is this possible?

Comment: You can have TypeScript create source maps, which can be used to relate the line and column informtaion back to the original TypeScript source. Debuggers can use them automatically, no idea how to integrate them into the logs you're dealing with, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get error information relating to TypeScript file lines number in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363449/how-to-get-error-information-relating-to-typescript-file-lines-number-in-node-js)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need a "source map" to map the JavaScript line numbers to TypeScript line numbers.

You can do this with the source-map-support node module.  First install it in your project:

```
npm install source-map-support
```

Then add this to your TypeScript file (index.ts):

```
require('source-map-support').install()
```

Then, if you function crashes, the line numbers should show TypeScript source lines.

Comment: That's really cool. (I kind of missed the fact it was Node.js running the function in the background, but...I didn't know that anyway, so. :-) )