# How to find line number in function which generated error in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, v8, stack-trace

I want know on executing code if some error is occured between try then need to know the linenumer in that function.

I have tried [Tracer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tracer) It gives me Function name,stack trace but line number given by it is wrong because it gives me line number from where `trace logger` was called not from where errro occured.

I have tried below code which can give me linenumber

```
 debugLine(error:Error) {
     if (error.stack!=undefined) {
        let frame = error.stack.split("\n")[1];
        let lineNumber = frame.split(":")[1];
        let functionName = frame.split(" ")[5];
        return functionName + ":" + lineNumber + " " + error.message;
     }

}
```

But if stack trace is complex then it does not guarantee the correct linenumber.  So which is the accurate and fast way to get the linenumber ?

Comment: What's an example where `error.stack` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I have no example as of now i am not sure if it in every case it will give us the correct line number.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing line numbers from the compiled Javascript (.js) files not the original Typescript sources (.ts files), which will lead to various discrepancies in the line numbers, depending on how much transformation has been done.

You can resolve this by using the `source-map-support` package in dev.

```
npm install --save-dev source-map-support
```

Ensure you install the package during your application boot (e.g. index.ts). You will want to remove this before deployment or add some environment switch.

```
require('source-map-support').install()
```

or

```
import {install} from 'source-map-support'
install()
```

And ensure Typescript compiler is emitting the source maps in
`tsconfig.json`

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50363693/209288